# How do I track session length in AWS Mobile Analytics?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

I'd like to report on session durations but that doesn't appear in the list of standard charts in the AWS Mobile Analytics console.

When the app enters the background I'd like to be able to get the session start and then calculate the interval.

Is this the (or a) correct approach? Or is this already available to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about that KPI not being available out of the box in the Mobile Analytics console.

And your idea also seems pretty spot on. The trouble with session duration is that it can be interpreted in multiple ways in the context of a mobile application so you'll have to decide on some business rules that make sense to you.

As far as your options for getting this metric, if you have [auto-export to RedShift enabled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/auto-export.html) in your console then here is a basic query you can start with:

```
SELECT session_id
       , DATEDIFF(second 
                , MIN(event_timestamp)
                , MAX(CASE WHEN event_type = '_session.stop' 
                          THEN session_stop_timestamp 
                           ELSE event_timestamp END)
                ) as session_duration
 FROM awsma.v_event
GROUP BY session_id
```

If you don't have auto-export enabled and don't want to go that route, an alternative would be to emit a custom event with a session duration metric that you compute in your app whenever your app is suspended. If you'd like to handle app crashes and potential context switches, where a user suspends the app for a short period of time (say call interrupts the session but the user goes back to the app right after) you may also choose to store the timestamp of when the app was suspended and only emit the session duration on resume - where you can make a determination about continuing the previous session or starting a new one.

If you decide to go the route of custom metrics, it's a good idea to bucketize session durations (say in 1 minute or 5 minute increments). Also, while there are no limitations on the number of unique values for a given custom metric, be mindful of other [limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/limits.html) such as total number of custom events, or total number of values for custom attribute values.